# How to redirect on get request to static image asset with Express

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to create a redirect after a get request to a static image asset using something like this but I can't figure it out.

Can anyone give me an idea?

```
app.get('/pixel-tracker.gif', function(req, res, next) {
    var options = {
    root: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    dotfiles: 'deny',
    headers: {
      'x-timestamp': Date.now(),
      'x-sent': true
    }
  }
  var fileName = req.params.name;
  res.sendFile(fileName, options, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      next(err)
    } else {
      console.log('Sent:', fileName);
      res.redirect('/pixel-parser');
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: There are some reasons this code doesn't make any sense.  1) You refer to `req.params.name`, but the route does not contain a `:name` parameter so `req.params.name` will always be `undefined`.  2) You pick either `res.sendFile()` or `res.redirect()`.  You can't do both.  You only get ONE response per request, not two.  Whichever you call second will get ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `res.redirect` after `res.sendFile` doesn't make sense. By calling `res.sendFile` you're responding with the file, i.e. you've already responded to the client and try to send another redirect response. You need to either send a file or redirect, can't do both.

Comment: I tried that before and it didn't work which lead me try to send file and then redirect.  The redirect works fine if I set it on any /route but doesn't work on /asset.gif get requests.

Comment: What was the error exactly and what do you try to achieve here? Why do you need a redirect there?

Comment: There wasn't an error at all. The gif asset loaded just fine but there was no redirect.

I tried something like this:

```app.get('/pixel-tracker.gif', function (req, res) {
   console.log("hello tracker");
   res.redirect('/pixel-parser');
});```

What I want to achieve is to send an email with a transparent pixel with an image source of /pixel-tracker.gif?revenue=amountofsale&clientid=valuefromusercookies.  When they user opens the email there is a request to the img url and then I want to redirect to and do an HTTP POST to a google analytics server to record an offline purchase.

Comment: So you send a file to a user, why do you want to redirect it? What's the goal?

Comment: It's not a file it's a transparent pixel gif used for analytics purposes.  For example let's say I'm car shopping online.  I fill out a form and my information along with a unique identifier gets sent to the dealers CRM system. Later thedealer sells me a car and they update my record in their CRM to assign a value to me equal to purchase price.  The dealer wants a way to know how I found his website so we send an email to the user w a transparent pixel and url params for the revenue amount and we grab the unique identifier from the users cookies in order to attribute revenue back to the source

Comment: In order to send the revenue back to Google analytics we will make a Post request to the GA servers and we have to have the unique identifier value that we are grabbing from the user when they open the email

Comment: If I understood correctly you receive `amount` and `clientId` in `/pixel-tracker.gif` handler. Can't you just POST to GA there? If you do a redirect then it will be GET redirect, not sure what this gives you...

Comment: If it's possible to do the post directly on that route then I agree that's better I just didn't think it possible. I will try that tomorrow and see what happens.

Comment: GA has [Measurment Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/) which you can send requests to from your server.
I don't think you can achieve the same with redirects. To do POST request from the client you'd have to use JS (AJAX) or submit html form which you can't do in email.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.

You can't set an app.post to fire on a route where you have a public asset. I removed the gif from the public folder and it works perfectly now.